# Ruby on Rails number_to_currency how to do without Unit [without symbol, $ or other]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to format my number with the helper `number_to_currency`, but show it without the currency symbol ($, R$, etc)?
Ex.:

```
$ 500,78  -> Not what i want
  500,78  -> Format i desire
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try using it with the `:unit` option set to empty string.

```
number_to_currency(1234567890.50, :unit => "")
```

Comment: `unit: ''`(no space) return with space which is not good for the currency field. How disable unit without space or string?

Comment: @AdrianoResende tracked your solution to https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26816

Comment: The accepted answer may still render a value with spaces if the currency format key value includes a string with spaces, in the locale file - as spaces are usually placed to separate the unit, from the value.
For a simple exception in code, you can use:

`number_to_currency(some_value, format: '%n')` which will render only the value parsed as currency without a unit.